# What's the meaning of an at sign on webpack's module exports resolve.alias?

Tags: webpack

While checking a React project that uses webpack I've noticed the following entry on the project's `webpack.config.js`:

```json
module.exports = {

  (...)

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolvePath('src'),
    },
  },

  (...)

}
```

I've combed through [webpack's documentation on resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) but there is zero mention of the at character.

Does anyone know what the at character means and where is it documented?

Answer (score 0):

It's not specifically related to webpack, just custom alias named `@`. It might be called `$` or `@src` or `whatever`.

It's a rather common abbreviation to make import paths look like `@/components/Button`.